# Group 2-dimensional PHP Array using 2 keys?

Tags: php, arrays, key, type-2-dimension

I'm a little stumped on this one. I think the best way to ask it is by giving an example. So I have this array:

```
$RN[0]['Brand']  = "AC"
      ['Number'] = "1234"
      ['Note']   = "12 Volt"

$RN[1]['Brand']  = "AC"
      ['Number'] = "1235"
      ['Note']   = "12 Volt"

$RN[2]['Brand']  = "Ford"
      ['Number'] = "7722"
      ['Note']   = "12 Volt"

$RN[3]['Brand']  = "AC"
      ['Number'] = "1236"
      ['Note']   = ""
```

And what I'd like to do is to combine elements based on the Note AND Brand, so both of those have to be identical in order to qualify to be grouped together. So the output would be something like this:

```
$RN[0]['Brand']   = "AC"
      ['Numbers'] = array( "1234", "1235" )
      ['Note']    = "12 Volt"

$RN[1]['Brand']   = "Ford"
      ['Numbers'] = array( "7722" )
      ['Note']    = "12 Volt"

$RN[2]['Brand']   = "AC"
      ['Numbers'] = array( "1236" )
      ['Note']    = ""
```

Thank you DaneSoul for pushing me in the right direction. For anybody interested, here is the final code - I started with his code and did some modifications to make it work in my situation:

```
$RN_new = array();
$i = 0;
$gotonext = 0;
foreach( $RN as $R ) {
    if ( isset( $RN_new ) && count( $RN_new ) > 0 ) {
        foreach( $RN_new as $key=>$RN_test ) {
            if ( $R['Brand'] == $RN_test['Brand'] && $R['Note'] == $RN_test['Note'] ) {
                $RN_new[$key]['Numbers'][] = $R['Number'];
                $gotonext = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    if ( $gotonext == 0 ) {
        $RN_new[$i]['Brand'] = $R['Brand'];
        $RN_new[$i]['Numbers'][] = $R['Number'];
        $RN_new[$i]['Note'] = $R['Note'];
        }
    $i++;
    $gotonext = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think he wants something like this: `$a[0, 'Brand'] = "AC";` -- Maybe this is what you want, but I can't be sure: `$RN = array(0 => array('Brand' => "AC", ...), ...);` -> `$RN[0]['Brand'] // "AC"`

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to take the first array (already declared) and transform it into the second array based on the given criteria... That is, if Brand and Note are both identical, combine those numbers into an array... So you can see in the example above that the two records that shared "AC" and "12 Volt" became one record with a Numbers array of both of the numbers which shared those traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$RN_new = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($RN as $RN_current){
  if($RN_current['Brand'] !== $RN_new[0]['Brand'] && 
     $RN_current['Note'] !== $RN_new[0]['Note']
  ){
     $RN_new[$i] = array('Brand' => $RN_current['Brand'], 
                         'Number' => array ($RN_current['Number']),
                         'Note' => $RN_current['Note']
                   );
  }
  else{
      $index = $i-1;
      $RN_new[$index]['Number'][] = $RN_current['Number']; 
  }
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Edited my unswer, have understood your task first not correctly.

Comment: Thanks, DaneSoul. I can see what you're trying to do here. It doesn't quite work as expected yet, but I'm working with it to try and get the right results. I'll mark as answered when I get it working.